# How to stop ringtone manager in firebase notification it is playing but not stoping

Tags: android

I have one FCM based notification when I am receiving notification I am playing custom mp3 from row folder. But once notification comes ringtone manager started playing mp3 but it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Once I am getting notification from FCM I set the sound to null and play custom notification through Ringtone manager. Please note size and length of notification should be small.

Comment: If anyone find any issue let me know will share some short of code also.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sound to the notification whilst building it rather than using RingtoneManager:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSound(soundUri); // Sound to play
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working on some devices like MI,Oppo devices.

Answer (score 0):

> When you want to stop your ringtone then Release your media player.